# How to count the total number of (CPU cycles) and (instructions retired) during the execution of the program?

Tags: c++

I program with C++ on Linux.

I have several competitor programs that performs the same tasks but in the different ways.

I want to compare those systems against mine in terms of CPU cycles spend and the number of instructions retired.

How to count the total number of (CPU cycles) and (instructions retired) during the execution of the program?

Do I need to access any hardware counter? or is there any well-known method to achieve it?

Comment: Good luck.  Many processor vendors recommend not counting CPU cycles as they can vary, depending on the state and load of the processor.  I recommend you time the execution for N samples and take the average.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's absolutely right. I will consider that.

Comment: One issue is that the OS can swap out portions of the executables to run other tasks.  So you would need to count the number of cycles that a program is executed by the OS.  Depends on the OS.

Comment: BTW, your question has nothing to do with the C++ language.  Executables can be written in any language.

Comment: Being aware of the unstabilty of the CPU cycles count, to actually get it, why not use `clock()` or `rdtsc()` and test the results? Average is indeed a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many tools to count cycles and instructions retired.  One widely accessible tool is Linux perf, which is described in detail on https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial.

From the aforementioned tutorial, you will find an answer that addresses your need directly:

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF8 perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10000000

100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
51200000 bytes (51 MB) copied, 0.0971547 s, 527 MB/s

 Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=100000':

       96,551,461 cycles
       38,176,009 instructions             #      0.395 IPC

       0.098556460  seconds time elapsed
```

This answer could be more complete.  You may also consider Intel Vtune, which provides similar hardware-aware profiling as Linux perf.  As you might imagine, Intel Vtune supports Intel processors, although it should support Linux, Mac and Windows (I have only used it on Linux).

Disclaimer: I work for Intel, but not in any capacity related to Vtune.

Comment: There's also AMD's [CodeAnalyst for Linux®](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/compute/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer-for-linux/).